# Md5 vs Md4 recognition

Tags: hash, md5

Is there a way to actually find out whether a hash is MD5 or MD4?

For instance:

- `10c7ccc7a4f0aff03c915c485565b9da` is an MD5 hash
- `be08c2de91787c51e7aee5dd16ca4f76` is an MD4 hash

I know that there is a difference "security wise" but how can someone determine which hash is which "programming wise" or just by the eyes. Or is there really no way to know for sure?

Answer (score 11):

> ... but how can someone determine which hash is which "programming wise" or just by the eyes. Or is there really no way to know for sure?

Both hash algorithms simply output bytes. There is no visible inherent structure in these bytes and no magic bytes or similar which could be used to detect the algorithm. In fact you would not be able to distinguish between MD4, MD5 or just 128 bit of random data just from looking at the output of the hash.

Comment: It is not true to say that there is no inherent structure in the bytes. We just do not know of any methods to detect such a structure, and may never know. Their security often relies on the assumed difficulty of finding such any bias in the digests. Neither MD5 nor MD4 are information theoretic secure hashes.

Comment: @mrparanoiac: changed this to "no visible inherent structure" to accept the possibility of some kind of super complex inherent structure nobody detected so far. But this does not change the reasoning and conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to do that. For this reason. Both are functions, where the input space is infinite (ok, its finite, because of the finite Damgard Merkle padding, but lets consider it infite. It practically is.).

The result space of both functions is 2^128, because both produce 128 bit digests.

So we have an almost unlimited domain and a limited codomain. So there is (almost) unlimited number of collisions for each target for both functions.

Hence you can't distinguish which function was used, because you are not even able to tell, what was the source for one of these functions...

There may be one exception: if some of the hash functions does not generate some part of its codomain (but this would almost certainly also mean that the function is terribly broken). Then you would be able to say for sure that it can't be that function....